# What's a better way to get around this error?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a JavaScript Tutorial. As I went on I decided to make a webpage in the shape of Flash Cards in order to summarize and practice JS concepts. Each JS concept is going to have its own HTML page with its respective Flash Cards, however, I didn't want to create a separate JS page for every script so I have just one "main.js" and I created some "onclick" event functions for each flash card which when clicked is supposed to show summarized information and demonstrate what that JS concept does.

Nevertheless, when I made my second HTML page and wrote the script, I stumbled upon this error: `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`  After a bit of research I discovered that it's some sort of conflict between the JS script in my first HTML page and the second. I don't actually fully understand what's going on behind this error since I thought my functions aren't being called automatic, you have to click on the cards for them to run so I don't know why the functions are returning "null".

But anyway, I was able to find a work around by wrapping all the the functions in a `If ("code" !== null)` but I wanted to know if there's a better and more effective way to do this, here's the full code:

```
// UI Functions

if (document.querySelector("#alert") && document.querySelector("#prompt") && document.querySelector("#confirm") !== null) {
  document.querySelector("#alert").onclick = function() {
    window.alert(`Message`);
  }

  document.querySelector("#prompt").onclick = function() {
    window.prompt(`What's your name?`, `What's your name?`);
  }

  document.querySelector("#confirm").onclick = function() {
    window.confirm(`Do you like learning JavaScript?`);
  }
}

// If-Else

if (document.querySelector("#ifelse") !== null) {
  document.querySelector("#ifelse").onclick = function() {
    const age = window.prompt(`How old are you?`);

    if (age < 3) {
      window.alert(`Hi, baby! Your age is ${age}`);
    } else if (age < 18) {
      window.alert(`Hello! Your age is ${age}`);
    } else if (age < 100) {
      window.alert(`Greetings! Your age is ${age}`);
    }
    else {
      window.alert(`What an unusual age! Your age is ${age}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable demo that reproduces the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With a setup like this, I don't see any benefit to using a single script. Given that the code per page is not that much, why not just use an internal `<script>` instead?

Comment: The browser console should output the line where you refer to the object that can't be found (null). Using a 'workaround' for such error doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't actually fully understand what's going on behind this error since I thought my functions aren't being called automatic, you have to click on the cards for them to run so I don't know why the functions are returning "null".

The error has virtually nothing to do with *those* functions.

Your code says "Get this element. When someone clicks on it, run this function".

Since the element doesn't exist, what happens is something like:

> *Code*: Get this element
>
> *Browser*: I can't find it
>
> *Code*: Now, when it is clicked on…
>
> *Browser* When **WHAT** is clicked on? I just said I couldn't find it.

---

> But anyway, I was able to find a work around by wrapping all the the functions in a If ("code" !== null)

You're only comparing the third one to null, the others you are just testing for truthiness.

> but I wanted to know if there's a better and more effective way to do this

Not hugely.

You could assign the results of `querySelector` to variables, and then use those variables for both the test and the assignment.

You could skip the comparison to `null` for the last one and just use the truthiness test there too.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I thought the script ignored those "non-existent" elements and just went on.